# DataStage recursion

Tags: database, etl, datastage

I have to find a leader of a group and update employee's leader. I am not sure how to proceed with this in DataStage.

I have an employee table as shown below

```
Emp_id   mgr_id   leader_id  
1        100      400
101      201      500
3        202      600
```

I get a file to update employee table when an employee changes group. Change code = CHG means it is a job/group change.

I do an equi join between file and employee table and can update manager id. At the same time, I need to find a leader. I need to get all the employees who report to that top level leader and use as the leader id's for every employee.

File:

```
emp_id  mgr_id  chg_cd
1       102     CHG
101     301     CHG
```

File Row 1: There is change in manager for emp_id = 1; need to update mgr_id, leader_id in employee table
File Row 2: There is change in manager for emp_id = 102, need to change mgr_id and leader_id for in employee table

Can you please suggest me on how to proceed with this in DataStage?

Comment: You haven't provided information how a leader can be identified and why it needs to be changed in your example.  In general if recursion is required I suggest to do it in SQL.

Comment: The file I get has history of all employees. I need to trace the leader in the file.If an employee changes a group the manager changes , I have to find the leader of that group and update emp.leader_id.Change code=CHG means job change.I know the ID of the org head is 9999 (which is same as emp_id; This id is also comes in the File).I have a situation in which the employees new manager may also change a group in that case I have find leader for the manager as well.  There is no table for leader id’s. Please let me know if this can be done in datastage

Comment: The leaders are the ones reporting to head of the org whose ID=9999. These are the leader id's I need to find.

Answer (score 0):

ok this problem requires a solution with recursion. As DataStage has no way to do it (if the levels between managers and leaders are variable).
So load the data into a database table and use recursive SQL to query it - this will provide you the solution you are asking for.

Example: 
Extract all leaders with their business units they manage inculding different levels) with the recursive SQL statement and use this data in da DataStage lookup to enrich the file data.

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to use just lookups to get this data in datastage?

Comment: If you know the maximum "depth" of the path yes - if you need a good and flexible implementation - no.